# Generate no. using temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate numbers from 1 to 100 without using loop. How can I do so?

Comment: And I want a pony. But to get back to the question, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please, show some effort. Hint to start: recursive CTE

Comment: At the risk of doing your homework for you, try recursion.

Comment: Hi, i want it in sql without using any loop

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Bart Why aim so low? I want a space shuttle!

Answer (score 2):

Recursive CTE:

```
with nums as (
   select 1 as num
   union all
   select num+1 from nums where num < 100
)
select num from nums
```

Now the philosophical question is: does your assignment consider recursion a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in T-SQL - it's the second statement in this blog entry:

http://trycatchfinally.net/2012/03/return-a-list-of-all-dates-between-a-start-and-end-date/

Basically, you're using the rows from the system tables and then using RANK() OVER() to number them between whatever range you want:

```
DECLARE @Start INT,
        @End   INT

    SET @Start = 1
    SET @End   = 100

;WITH numberlist(number)
   AS (SELECT RANK() over(order by c1.object_id,
                                   c1.column_id,
                                   c2.object_id,
                                   c2.column_id)
         from sys.columns c1
        cross
         join sys.columns c2)
SELECT @Start + number - 1
  FROM numberlist
 WHERE @Start + number - 1 <= @End
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and execute the following stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @sequence int
UPDATE YourTable SET sequence  = sequence  + 1, @sequence  = sequence  + 1
SELECT @sequence  AS ‘sequence’
```